# Upload File to Cloud Storage directly using SignedURL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file directly to Google Cloud Storage using [Java Client Library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/package-summary.html)

The Code I have written is

[image: Java Code]

Instead of uploading the new file to cloud storage I am getting this output
 [image: Output]

What I am missing in the code to make the upload to Cloud Storage ?

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Instead copy-paste it in the question and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Include all your source code. 2) Do not include pictures of your source code, include the actual text. 3) Where are you getting `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_EMAIL`, etc? These values are part of your credentials json file. You should be loading these values from that file. 4) You do not need to specify scope. That is defined by your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the correct "BUCKET_NAME" set, please compare the bucket name you are using with your bucket name on your Google Cloud Console so you can see if it's set correctly.

The way it's set, it looks like the compiler thought you were using a different constructor for your [blobInfo.newBuilder method](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/storage/BlobInfo.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need configure the the authorization keys, is a file .json to you enverioment,see this in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-gcloud